# PC cannot ping another PC on my home network

Tags: networking

I am running Windows 7 on my PC, and I am running a Windows 2008 Server VM in Windows Virtual PC.  Both machines have network connectivity.  However, I cannot ping the VM from the host neither by computer name nor IP.  I can ping the host machine from the VM both by computer name and IP.

Is there something I need to enable on the VM to allow it to be seen by other machines on my network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how Windows Virtual PC works, but VM software typically support 3 networking setups for the virtual machine.  In bridged mode, the virtual machine appears on your outside network with a unique mac and ip address.  In nat mode, the VM is hidden behind firewall on the host machine, but can still reach the external network.  In host mode, the VM can talk to the host machine and other similarly configured VMs on the host, but nobody else.

I realize that doesn't exactly answer your question, but my recommendation is to first determine which mode the VM in question is configured to use.

Comment: Actually, I've determined it to be a firewall issue as it works after I disable Windows Firewall.  Not sure how to adjust it to allow an IP range.